# Tough geometry question (stuck for hours)

Tags: geometry

The basic problem comes from a real-life situation where I have to figure out how far to place a camera with FOV $\phi$ in $\theta$ angle above the $x$ axis in order to view a bounding box with sides $x,y$

The only parameters are the sides of the rectangle $x, y$, and angles $\theta, \phi$

(e.g $\angle FAK$ is not $90^\circ$)

The objective is to find the length of $FN$

I've been trying over and over, constructing tens of equations using the sine rules etc., to no avail.

Help would be much appreciated!

Any hints as to how to generally approach those kind of problems except trying over and over to construct cascading expressions will also be helpful :)

[image: Problem picture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $N$ as the origin of a coordinate system. Given points $A = (-x/2, y/2)$ and $D = (x/2, -y/2)$, you need to find $d$ such that from the camera's position $F = (d \sin \theta, d \cos \theta)$, the vectors $\overrightarrow{FA}$ and $\overrightarrow{FD}$ make an angle $\phi$. Recall that the dot product of two vectors is the product of their magnitudes and the cosine of the angle separating them, so the algebraic expression you need to solve for $d$ is is $$\cos \phi = \frac{\overrightarrow{FA} \cdot \overrightarrow{FD}}{\left|\overrightarrow{FA}\right| \left|\overrightarrow{FD}\right|} = \frac{(d^2 \sin^2 \theta - x^2/4) + (d^2 \cos^2 \theta - y^2/4)}{\sqrt{(d \sin \theta - x/2)^2 + (d \cos \theta + y/2)^2} \sqrt{(d \sin \theta + x/2)^2 + (d \cos \theta - y/2)^2}}$$
which gives you a messy, but solvable, quadratic equation for $d^2$.

Comment: Coordinates system to the rescue!

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding something but the dot product of FA and FD is wrong?

$(d*sin \theta - \frac x 2)^2 + (d*cos \theta - \frac y 2)^2$

Comment: Nope, the dot product is correct as it stands.

Comment: You are right, my mistake!

Comment: Is there any hope of finding an 'elegant' trig-based solution to this?

Comment: I'd doubt it, though if $\phi$ were defined as the distance from $A$ to $N$ rather than from $A$ to $D$, then application of the law of sines to the triangle $AFN$ would solve the problem, and if $\phi$ is very small then there are some asymptotic simplifications possible.